# django get existing objects and update m2m

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

models.py

```
class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name='phonenumbers', blank=True)
    employee = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, related_name='phonenumbers', blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

For check exist phone I tried create save() method for PhoneNumber model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     #check if phone exists
     exist_phone = PhoneNumber.objects.filter(phone=self.phone).last()
     if exist_phone:
         new_people = self.person
         if new_people:
             for person in new_people:
                 exist_phone.person.add(person)
         new_employees = self.employee
         if new_employees:
             for employee in new_employees:
                 exist_phone.employee.add(employee)
     else:
         super(PhoneNumber, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It doesn't work because an error occurs:

```
"<PhoneNumber: >" needs to have a value for field "phonenumber" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

But I want get existing object and add new value for m2m. How do i get values from posted m2m fields? Is there are possible to realize it in model?

**Update**

It's not possible to realize this in model.
I use drf and realized get_or_create in serializer

```
class PhoneNumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PhoneNumber
        fields = ('id', 'person', 'employee', 'phone')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        people = validated_data.pop('person')
        employees = validated_data.pop('employee')
        phone = validated_data['phone']
        exist_phone = PhoneNumber.objects.filter(phone=phone).last()

        if exist_phone:
            phonenumber = exist_phone
            for person in people:
                person.phonenumbers.add(phonenumber)
            for employee in employees:
                employee.phonenumbers.add(phonenumber)
        else:
            phonenumber = PhoneNumber.objects.create(**validated_data)

        return phonenumber
```

This is not very convenient, because you need to do the same for both drf and admin and for other forms.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Signal` in this case because M2M field can save after creating instance.

I think that you use `post_save`.

I recommend you read this doc.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

Comment: I known about signal but in this situation I need get existing (without creating new) object and pass there the m2m values